# How to know whether a property stored in DbEntityEntry is a property`?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

In Entity Framework 6 within an `DbEntityEntry` certain information can be retrieved by calling `Property`. 
However, this fails with an `ArgumentException` when the property is not a property but a collection or reference. Than other functions must be used.

How can I know which function to call? That is, how can I know of what type (simple property, complex property, reference, collection) the property is?

For DbEntityEntry see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry%28v=vs.113%29.aspx

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Have you solved your problem? I have exactly same suituation.

Comment: I progresssed one step - but not fully yet. I will post later today (code not available to me right now)

Comment: I have also achive to find if the navigation property is collection type or not. I have posted it as answer. Please, let me know your way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`DbEntityEntry.Member(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbentityentry.member(v=vs.113).aspx) returns a `DbMemberEntry`, which you can check with `(memberEntry is DbPropertyEntry)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have find how to get if the navigation property is collection type or not.
For this, we need to get `BuiltInTypeKind` of the property.

I am using this code for getting all navigation properties of the entity:

```
var entitySetElementType = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().EntitySet.ElementType;
var navProperties = entitySetElementType.NavigationProperties;
```

Then, we can know if th navigation property is collection or not:

```
foreach (var navigationProperty in entiySetElementType.NavigationProperties)
{
      var builtInType = navigationProperty.TypeUsage.EdmType.BuiltInTypeKind;
      var isCollection = builtInType == System.Data.Metadata.Edm.BuiltInTypeKind.CollectionKind
                      || builtInType == System.Data.Metadata.Edm.BuiltInTypeKind.CollectionType;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Since EF has been moved to a separate assembly & namespace, the `System.Data.Metadata.Edm.BuiltInTypeKind.CollectionKind` in above code should be changed to `System.Data.Entity.Core.Metadata.Edm.BuiltInTypeKind.CollectionKind`.

Answer (score 1):

One of the steps is to dig through those dynamic proxies. I do it with:

```
    if ( targetType.BaseType != null
        && targetType.Namespace == "System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies" )
    {
        targetType = targetType.BaseType;
    }
```

Not really clean, but does the job.

***Update***

Based on jjj's answer, I came up with the following method:

```
        private bool IsSimpleProperty( string propertyName, DbEntityEntry entry )
        {
            DbMemberEntry memberEntry = entry.Member( propertyName );

            return memberEntry is DbPropertyEntry;
        }
```

By varying the is expression, you could check for all types.